# C# DataGridView - Transparent Image

Tags: c#, datagridview, transparency

I am attempting to populate a DataGridView cell with an image. The image is a 32bit png with Alpha Transparency.

I can get this image to display properly in a picturebox or a Listview but in the DataGridView the image loses quality.

I have tried setting various parts of the control to transparent but nothing seems to work. I import the image into resource file and then call it directly.

I have a feeling I need to override the onpaint event to resolve the transparency/color depth issue but I'm not entirely sure.

I would appreciate any help!

The top image is that from a picturebox and the bottom two are in the DataGridView.

*Since I am unable to use an image tag, please see the following link for an example of the problem

http://bytes.com/attachments/attachment/2016d1245038555/imageissue.png

Comment: Add a DataGridView control to your form. Add the following code to formload: Bitmap testImage = new Bitmap(@"C:\pathtoyourimage.png"); dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells; DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn(); dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imageColumn); dataGridView1.Rows.Add(testImage);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested with a lower resolution gif and it looks acceptable. The PNG I was using is 32-Bit (with 8 bits alpha channel) and I think this is simply out of the depth that the DataGridView Image Column can handle.

Thanks to everyone who offered their input.  It is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem. My 32 bits png image looked horrible in a DataGridView. What I did is convert my png file to the .ico format (I used http://www.convertico.com/), and then added it to the grid.

What I did is set displayCell.ValueIsIcon = True to make the DataGridViewImageCell treat my image as an Icon.

And that did it for me. The icons look good now...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but it appears that this might be a resizing issue rather than a transparency issue (or a problem with the resizing/transparency interaction).  Try using a PNG file that has exactly the same pixel-by-pixel dimensions as the size to which it's rendered in the DataGridView.

Comment: I wish that were it but I can make the cell height the exact size or larger than the image and it still appears as shown in the example.

Comment: Can you post a code sample, or better yet a link to a simple project that shows this problem? I'm curious about this because it's a weird problem, but I don't feel like figuring out the basics of loading images into a DataGridView. It looks kind of like the DataGridView is trying (and failing miserably) to draw some sort of border effect around the image.

Comment: Add a DataGridView control to your form.

Add the following code to formload:

            Bitmap testImage = new Bitmap(@"C:\pathtoyourimage.png");
            
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
            DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imageColumn);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(testImage);

Comment: @NSH: I think your problem is either something weird about your computer or something weird about the PNG file you're using. Using your sample code (thank you), I was able to load a bunch of different PNG files (all with trasnparency) in the DataGridView, and they all looked perfect and normal (no weird artifacts). Post a link to your original PNG file and I'll see what that looks like on my computer.

Comment: I have tested with a lower resolution gif and it looks acceptable. The PNG I was using is 32-Bit (with 8 bits alpha channel) and I think this is simply out of the depth that the DataGrideView Image Column can handle.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem using an ImageList, once I switched to a Bitmap Array, it worked fine.